# deck of cards using methods and multiple classes

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm getting no output and not sure where to go from here.

> Design and implement a class called Card, which represents a standard playing card. Each card has a suit and a face value. Then, create a driver class that stores 52 objects of the Card class into an array. Include methods to shuffle the deck, deal a card and report the number of cards left in the deck. The shuffle method should assume a full deck. Your main method should deal each card from a shuffled deck, printing each card (suit and face value) as it is dealt.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    import java.util.Random;
public class card {
public static void main(String[] args) {}

    public class deck {


        int[] deck = new int[52];
        String[] suits = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
        String[] ranks = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

        public void create() {//initialize cards
            for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) deck[i] = i;
        }


        public void shuffle() {//deck shuffle
            for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {

                int index = (int) (Math.random() * deck.length);
                int temp = deck[i];
                deck[i] = deck[index];
                deck[index] = temp;
            }



                 //display all the cards!
                for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)

                {
                    String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
                    String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];
                    System.out.println("Card number " + deck[i] + ": " + rank + " of " + suit);


                }


            }
        }

        }
```

Comment: Unrelated, but using consistent indentation and removing spurious whitespace makes code a lot easier to read and reason about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java, the method main() is where your code will start running. You have nothing in your main method right now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

To get it to do something, change it to something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 deck myDeck = new deck();
 myDeck.create();
 myDeck.shuffle();
}
```

As a note, it is good practice in java to name your classes with capital letters.

Comment: I have done that, and it is telling me my new deck cannot be referenced from a static context. What did I miss lol UPDATE I made deck static seems to work!!!!

Comment: If my solution helped you solve your problem, it would be great if you marked it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I tried to write some code for you, its not complete, but provides a framework for you to continue, all you have to do is implement your own shuffle method and add more variables to ranks:

```
public class CardDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Deck myDeck = new Deck();
        myDeck.shuffle();
        System.out.println("Dealt cards are:");
        myDeck.dealAllCards();
    }
}

class Card {
    String suite, faceValue;
    Card(String suite, String faceValue) {
        this.suite = suite;
        this.faceValue = faceValue;
    }
    void printCard() {
        System.out.println(faceValue + " " + suite);
    }
}

class Deck {
    String[] suits = { "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs" };
    String[] ranks = { "6", "7" };
    int count = ranks.length * suits.length;
    Card deck[] = new Card[count];

    Deck() { // fills out the deck
        int index = 0; // this is for simple deck filling
        for (int i = 0; i < ranks.length; i++) { // for ranks
            for (int j = 0; j < suits.length; j++) { // for suits
                deck[index] = new Card(suits[j], ranks[i]);
                index++;
            }
        }
    };

    void shuffle() { // shuffles the deck
        // your code here
    }

    Card dealCard() { // gives card from deck
        if (returnLeft() > 0) {
            count--;
            return deck[count];
        } else return null;
    }

    int returnLeft() {
        return count;
    }

    void dealAllCards() {
        int counter = count;
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            Card someCard = dealCard();
            someCard.printCard();
        }
    }
}
```